# SQL column count

Tags: sql

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to expected result from the attached screenshot

```
month          empid    emp_name             p count     wo count   Totalhrs
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
FEB       00113   HUda salem al kaabi     25         4         1250
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results

Comment: Poor sample data when it's only one person, and one month. Less data, but more complex would be great - to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a query like this :

```sql
Select
    empid
    max(emp_name)                                 as emp_name,
    count(*)                                      as count,
    sum(case when dstatus='wo' then 1 else 0 end) as wo_count,
    sum(total_hrs)                                as totalhrs
from
    <your_table>
where
   p_date like '2020-10%'
group by
    empid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select empid, emp_name,
    sum(case when dstatus = 'P'  then 1 else 0 end) p_count,
    sum(case when dstatus = 'WO' then 1 else 0 end) wo_count,
    sum(total_hrs) total_hrs
from mytable
group by empid, emp_name
```

Comment: month        empid    emp_name        p count       wo count           Totalhrs

02-2020     113           joyal                      25              4                      1250

Comment: @JoyalGeorge: you could add `year(pDate)` and `month(pDate)` to both the `select` and `group by` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT empid, emp_name, COUNT(*) 'p count', COUNT( IIF(DSTATUS = 'WO',1,0 )) 'wo count', COUNT(Total_Hrs) 'Total Hours' 
    FROM tb
GROUP BY empid, emp_name, p_count, wo_count, Total_Hrs
```